# XOR operation on bytes

Tags: java, byte, xor

I am trying to understand the working of XOR on bytes

```
    byte byte1 = (byte)0x00;
    byte byte2 = (byte)0x80;
    int x = ((byte1^byte2));
    System.out.println("Value of X is "+x);
    int x1 = ((byte1^byte2)&0xff);
    System.out.println("Value of X1 is "+x1);
```

The output displayed is:

```
   Value of X is -128
   Value of X1 is 128
```

Here I am trying to perform XOR on byte1 and byte2 and then mask it with 0xff.
byte1^byte2 gives me value of -128. When I perform an AND with the result and 11111111 I am getting 128. Does this mean that, to convert a signed byte to a unsigned byte we mask it with 0xff? I am trying to understand how it works as it is pretty confusing. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried: `int x1=((byte1^byte2)&((byte)0xff));`?

Comment: It gives me -128 for this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "upcast" integer primitive types, the sign bit is carried.

In:

```
int x = byte1 ^ byte2;
```

in fact, both bytes are converted to integers. And since `byte2` is (in binary) `1000 0000`, aka 0x80, its integer value will be... 0xffffff80.

In your second example, byte1 ^ byte2 also gives 0xffffff80, but since you and it with 0x000000ff, you do get 0x00000080 which is 128.

Note that since Java 7 you can do `byte b = (byte) 0b1000_0000`; in your situation, you may want to use binary instead of hexadecimal, but that's your choice.

Comment: when I tried to print byte1^byte2, it is displaying -128. From what I understand, byte1^byte2 gives me 1000 0000. If the left-most bit is 1 , it means that the number is negative. To get the magnitude, we minus one then invert the bits :

10000000 - 1 = 01111111:
01111111 inverted = 10000000:

10000000 when interpreted as a decimal number is 128. So we have a negative number with a magnitude of 128, giving us -128.          so in the case of int x = byte1 ^ byte2; where the value is 0xffffff80 do we consider the last 8 bits?